# GRID CSS: Cómo puedo hacer para que las filas se ajusten al tamaño del contenido

Tags: html, css, css-grid-layout

Estoy haciendo con grid unas 3 columnas y en cada de ellas tienen texto, el problema radica en la altura de la fila, ya que grid lo que hace es colocar la altura más alta de uno de los contenidos por defecto, y esa altura se la proporciona al resto.

Deseo simplemente que se adapten al contenido, he usado la propiedad min-content y no he tenido éxito.

Una solución que he visto es usar flex-box, ya que este si permite que las filas se adapten al contenido.

Pero igual deseo saber si con css grid hay solucion.

```css
.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: min-content;
}

.container__item{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__item">Uno de los peores defectos que tienen los que desarrollan software es la inconstancia: acumular tareas lo que trae agobio, las prisas, las horas extras y aquí comienza a resentirse la calidad del trabajo.  Rafael Gómez<br><br>Uno de los peores defectos que tienen los que desarrollan software es la inconstancia: acumular tareas lo que trae agobio, las prisas, las horas extras y aquí comienza a resentirse la calidad del trabajo.  Rafael Gómez<br><br>Uno de los peores defectos que tienen los que desarrollan software es la inconstancia: acumular tareas lo que trae agobio, las prisas, las horas extras y aquí comienza a resentirse la calidad del trabajo.  Rafael Gómez<br><br>Uno de los peores defectos que tienen los que desarrollan software es la inconstancia: acumular tareas lo que trae agobio, las prisas, las horas extras y aquí comienza a resentirse la calidad del trabajo.  Rafael Gómez</div>
  <div class="container__item">Un buen desarrollador de software trabaja con disciplina y constancia desde el primer día”.  Omar Bradley<br><br></div>
  <div class="container__item">Tienes que aprender a aprovechar la tecnología para poder usarla para cosas positivas sin estar desconectado de la naturaleza.-Talib Kweli.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

puedes solucionarlo agregando un 'height: fit-content' en las clases "container__item"

```css
.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: min-content;
}

.container__item{
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>prube</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="container__item">Uno de los peores defectos que tienen los que desarrollan software es la inconstancia: acumular tareas lo que trae agobio, las prisas, las horas extras y aquí comienza a resentirse la calidad del trabajo.  Rafael Gómez<br><br>Uno de los peores defectos que tienen los que desarrollan software es la inconstancia: acumular tareas lo que trae agobio, las prisas, las horas extras y aquí comienza a resentirse la calidad del trabajo.  Rafael Gómez<br><br>Uno de los peores defectos que tienen los que desarrollan software es la inconstancia: acumular tareas lo que trae agobio, las prisas, las horas extras y aquí comienza a resentirse la calidad del trabajo.  Rafael Gómez<br><br>Uno de los peores defectos que tienen los que desarrollan software es la inconstancia: acumular tareas lo que trae agobio, las prisas, las horas extras y aquí comienza a resentirse la calidad del trabajo.  Rafael Gómez</div>
      <div class="container__item">Un buen desarrollador de software trabaja con disciplina y constancia desde el primer día”.  Omar Bradley<br><br></div>
      <div class="container__item">Tienes que aprender a aprovechar la tecnología para poder usarla para cosas positivas sin estar desconectado de la naturaleza.-Talib Kweli.</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Espero que sea la respuesta que buscabas ;)

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes lograr con la propiedad `height: min-content;`, así indicas que su altura ocupará el contenido mínimo que conlleva dentro de cada `container__item`.

#### Ejemplo:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: min-content;
}

.container__item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: min-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__item">Uno de los peores defectos que tienen los que desarrollan software es la inconstancia: acumular tareas lo que trae agobio, las prisas, las horas extras y aquí comienza a resentirse la calidad del trabajo.  Rafael Gómez<br><br>Uno de los peores defectos que tienen los que desarrollan software es la inconstancia: acumular tareas lo que trae agobio, las prisas, las horas extras y aquí comienza a resentirse la calidad del trabajo.  Rafael Gómez<br><br>Uno de los peores defectos que tienen los que desarrollan software es la inconstancia: acumular tareas lo que trae agobio, las prisas, las horas extras y aquí comienza a resentirse la calidad del trabajo.  Rafael Gómez<br><br>Uno de los peores defectos que tienen los que desarrollan software es la inconstancia: acumular tareas lo que trae agobio, las prisas, las horas extras y aquí comienza a resentirse la calidad del trabajo.  Rafael Gómez</div>
  <div class="container__item">Un buen desarrollador de software trabaja con disciplina y constancia desde el primer día”.  Omar Bradley</div>
  <div class="container__item">Tienes que aprender a aprovechar la tecnología para poder usarla para cosas positivas sin estar desconectado de la naturaleza.-Talib Kweli.</div>
</div>
```